# Return value from callback in Python (Vizard)

Tags: python, callback, return-value

I am using Vizard (Python) to change a boolean variable whenever the mouse is clicked. In order to detect mouse clicks, Vizard uses the function `viz.callback()`. My code is as follows, and I am trying to change the state of `flag` from True to False:

```
def onMouseClick(flag):
    if flag:
        flag = False
    return flag

flag = True
viz.callback(viz.MOUSEDOWN_EVENT,onMouseClick(flag))
```

The trouble is, I don't know how to get the return value of `flag` out of the function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use classes to handle the clicking:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, flag=False):
        self.flag = flag

    def flip_flag(self):
        self.flag = not self.flag

bar = Foo()
print(bar.flag)    # Prints False
viz.callback(viz.MOUSEDOWN_EVENT, bar.flip_flag)

# After some MOUSEDOWN_EVENT
print(bar.flag)    # Prints True
```

This is just my basic example. See the Vizard docs for 'better' [Event Handling](http://docs.worldviz.com/vizard/Event_Basics.htm).